# Ошибкак 404 при попытке создать GET запрос в javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется три файла (взято из примера: https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/3523261-use-javascript-in-your-web-projects/3759261-make-your-first-ajax-request)

**ajax-example.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles-ajax.css">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<script>
    var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    myRequest.open('GET', 'surprise-ajax.html');
    myRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (myRequest.readyState === 4) {
            document.getElementById('ajax-content').innerHTML = myRequest.responseText;
        }
    };

    function sendTheAJAX() {
        myRequest.send();
        document.getElementById('reveal').style.display = 'none';
    }

</script>
<body>
<h1>Today's your special day!</h1>
<button id="reveal" onclick="sendTheAJAX()" class="button">Why's that?</button>
<div id="ajax-content">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**surprise-ajax.html**

```
<h1 id="birthday-greeting">It's your birthday!</h1>
```

Ну и **style-ajax.css**

```
body {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    text-align: center;
}

#birthday-greeting {
    font-size: 72px;
    color: red;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Страница выводится. Но при нажатии кнопки `Why's that?` получаю ошибку 404:

```
{"timestamp":"2018-12-18T17:29:06.593+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/surprise-ajax.html"}
```

Файл surprise-ajax.html разместил во всех папках пректа, но ситуацию не меняет.

Как решить?

Comment: Как выглядит в адресной строке браузера url текущей страницы? Не могли в название файла попасть русские буквы?

Comment: @Igor, текущая страница прописана в контроллере, в 'java' проекте: в браузере вызывается следующей урлой: http://localhost:8080/test-ajax . По поводу русских букв Вы близки - была и такая ошибка. В данном случае - точно нет

Comment: Судя по вашему запросу, файл должен быть доступен на url `localhost:8080/surprise-ajax.html`. Вбейте это в строку адреса браузера. Правильный путь до вашего файла зависит от роутинга на сервере.